# Changing default new editor group location on VS Code

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code, customization

Strangely enough, I haven't been able to find questions over SO or through search engines in general of people who want to change where VS Code opens a new editor group by default. In my case, I am trying to make the MSSQL extension open a query's results in a pane **below** the current one.

However, there doesn't seem to be a ready solution for this. In `settings.json`, it is possible to change the behaviour of these splits directly:

`"mssql.splitPaneSelection":"current"`

However, the only possible values this field can take are `next`, `current` and `end`. I also tried to change editor positioning on the workbench settings:

`"workbench.editor.openPositioning": "left"`

But this setting doesn't have a `below` option as well, only `left`, `right`, `first` and `last`.

Is it possible to make these panels open below the current editor? If so, how and how to carry these settings to the MSSQL extension? (most likely using `next` or `end` as the parameter for a new pane)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out randomly in the VS Code [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface). All you need is to set the direction in `settings.json`:

`"workbench.editor.openSideBySideDirection": "down"`

I haven't tested with the MSSQL extension since I'm not using it anymore, but it should be fine if I'd guess.